# Node by node animation is not rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, path-finding

I am trying to implement Clement's Pathfinding visualizer by watching his Youtube tutorial.
However, my node by node animation is not getting rendered even if I provide the delay for each node animation.
Can you please take a look at the code?

The output I want is the node by node animation

Also, I am new to React JS and a beginner at JavaScript. Although I understand what is going on, on the surface level, it is a bit difficult to make changes like this. Can you also suggest what can I do to strengthen my fundamentals.

Thank you

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import Node from './Node/Node';
import './Node/Node.css'

import './PathfindingVisualizer.css';
//import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import {dijkstra_algorithm as dijkstra} from '../algorithms/dijkstra'

const START_NODE_ROW = 10;
const START_NODE_COL = 15;
const FINISH_NODE_ROW = 15; 
const FINISH_NODE_COL = 30;

export default class PathfindingVisualizer extends Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={
        grid: [],
        mouseIsPressed: false
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const grid= getInitialGrid();
        this.setState({grid});
    }

    animateDijkstra(visitedNodesInOrder) {
        visitedNodesInOrder.forEach((node, i) => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState((prevState) => {
              const newGrid = prevState.grid.slice();
              const newNode = {
                ...node,
                isVisited: true,
              };
              newGrid[node.row][node.col] = newNode;
              return { grid: newGrid };
            });
          }, 1000 * i); // Delay each animation by 1000 milliseconds (1 second)
        });
      }
      
      
      
      

    visualizeDijkstra(){
        const {grid} = this.state;
        const startNode=grid[START_NODE_ROW][START_NODE_COL];
        const finishNode=grid[FINISH_NODE_ROW][FINISH_NODE_COL];
        const visitedNodesInOrder=dijkstra(grid, startNode,finishNode);
        this.animateDijkstra(visitedNodesInOrder);
    }

    /*handleMouseEnter(row, col) {
        if (!this.state.mouseIsPressed) return;
        const newGrid = getNewGridWithWallToggled(this.state.grid, row, col);
        this.setState({grid: newGrid});
    }
    
    handleMouseUp() {
    this.setState({mouseIsPressed: false});
    }*/

    render(){
        const {grid}=this.state;

        return(
            <>
                <button onClick={() => this.visualizeDijkstra()}>
                    Visualize Dijkstra Algorithm
                </button>
            <div className="grid">
                {grid.map((row,rowIdx)=>{
                    return(
                        <div key={rowIdx}>
                            {row.map((node,nodeIdx) => {
                            const {isStart, isFinish, isVisited} = node;
                            return(
                                
                                <Node
                                    key={nodeIdx}
                                    isStart={isStart}
                                    isFinish={isFinish}
                                    isVisited={isVisited}
                                    >

                                </Node>
                            );
                        })}
                        </div>
                    );
                    })}
                
            </div>
        </>
        );
    }
}
const getInitialGrid = () => {
    const grid=[];
   
    for(let row=0; row<20; row++){
        const currentRow=[];
        for(let col=0; col<50; col++){
            currentRow.push(createNode(col,row));
        }
            
            grid.push(currentRow);
        }
    return grid;
};

const createNode = (col, row) => {
    return{
        col,
        row,
        isStart: row === START_NODE_ROW && col === START_NODE_COL,
        isFinish: row === FINISH_NODE_ROW && col ===FINISH_NODE_COL,
        distance: Infinity,
        isVisited: false,
        //isWall: false,
        previousNode: null,
    };
};
```

This is my output in one go.

[image]

Comment: Can you make an example here? https://codesandbox.io/s/react-new

Comment: Hi, I have saved my code on the link.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/falling-tdd-2rw5t5?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are changing the grid while doing the calculations and stuff... and when you click to start rendering, the grid is already all set. I prevented that by having a copy of the empty grid in the state and loop through this empty one (copy using `structuredClone` to do a deep copy, if you copy by spreading `...` or `.slice()` it would make a shallow copy and the same problem would happen)

https://codesandbox.io/s/spring-star-sgn2s5?file=/src/PathfindingVisualizer/PathfindingVisualizer.jsx

**PathfindingVisualizer.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Node from "./Node/Node";
import "./Node/Node.css";

import "./PathfindingVisualizer.css";
import { dijkstra_algorithm as dijkstra } from "../algorithms/dijkstra";

const START_NODE_ROW = 10;
const START_NODE_COL = 15;
const FINISH_NODE_ROW = 15;
const FINISH_NODE_COL = 30;

export default class PathfindingVisualizer extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      grid: [],
      animatedGrid: [], //  new state to have an empty grid
      mouseIsPressed: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const grid = getInitialGrid();
    this.setState({
      grid,
      animatedGrid: structuredClone(grid) //  passing a deepcopy of the grid
    });
  }

  animateDijkstra(visitedNodesInOrder) {
    visitedNodesInOrder.forEach((node, i) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState((prevState) => {
          const newGrid = prevState.animatedGrid;
          const newNode = {
            ...node,
            isVisited: true
          };
          newGrid[node.row][node.col] = newNode;
          return { animatedGrid: newGrid };
        });
      }, 30 * i); //  CHANGE BACK TO 1000 FOR 1 second
    });
  }

  visualizeDijkstra() {
    const { grid } = this.state;
    const startNode = grid[START_NODE_ROW][START_NODE_COL];
    const finishNode = grid[FINISH_NODE_ROW][FINISH_NODE_COL];
    const visitedNodesInOrder = dijkstra(grid, startNode, finishNode);
    this.animateDijkstra(visitedNodesInOrder);
  }

  render() {
    const { animatedGrid } = this.state; //  using the new state here

    return (
      <>
        <button onClick={() => this.visualizeDijkstra()}>
          Visualize Dijkstra Algorithm
        </button>
        <div className="grid">
          {animatedGrid.map((row, rowIdx) => {
            //  using the new state here
            return (
              <div key={rowIdx}>
                {row.map((node, nodeIdx) => {
                  const { isStart, isFinish, isVisited } = node;
                  return (
                    <Node
                      key={nodeIdx}
                      isStart={isStart}
                      isFinish={isFinish}
                      isVisited={isVisited}
                    ></Node>
                  );
                })}
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}
const getInitialGrid = () => {
  const grid = [];

  for (let row = 0; row < 20; row++) {
    const currentRow = [];
    for (let col = 0; col < 50; col++) {
      currentRow.push(createNode(col, row));
    }

    grid.push(currentRow);
  }
  return grid;
};

const createNode = (col, row) => {
  return {
    col,
    row,
    isStart: row === START_NODE_ROW && col === START_NODE_COL,
    isFinish: row === FINISH_NODE_ROW && col === FINISH_NODE_COL,
    distance: Infinity,
    isVisited: false,
    previousNode: null
  };
};
```